# Angular version 6 Blank page and no errors on HTML Render error

Tags: html, angular

This must be the most frustrating thing about working with Angular.

Why does Angular NOT tell you what HTML page there is a render error in? It just defaults to the route page and tells you nothing.

This time (Luckily) I know there's some random error on SomePage.html, because if I comment out the page, everything works fine, but for those times that I don't know what page the error is in, its TOTAL CHAOS of me commenting out random pages trying to find the needle in my haystack.

Why does this happen and is there a way to get more info out of angular!?

Just look at the nice and Clean Console window, not telling me anything. So useful. So great.

[image]

Edit: And I finally found the Error, it was literally just not having a doulbe '=' sign and instead I had 1.

```
*ngIf="someType = 'user'"
```

instead of

```
*ngIf="someType == 'user'"
```

How Dumb is this?

Comment: are you using angularjs or angular?
Might wanna edit your tags.

Also did you notice that you filtered the console output?

Comment: Ah my bad. Thanks @Arikael

Comment: are you seeing anything in your IDEs console?
What happens when you don't filter the browsers console output?
Have you tried using the `---verbose` parameter? (https://angular.io/cli/serve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found a way. Should probably have thought about this before.

Just run the debugger and you'll get exactly what the problem is.

[image]